# How to Disable initial data load in Reference Search Editor in hybris backoffice

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Disable initial load of data in reference search.
I want to avoid loading entire data in reference search and if I click on Search button, I want to load data.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add disable-auto-search="true" to the advanced search context in backoffice-config.xml file as below. It works for any type.

Comment: <context type="Product" component="advanced-search" merge-by="type" parent="GenericItem">
  <advanced-search xmlns:advanced-search="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/advancedsearch" xmlns="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/advancedsearch" disable-auto-search="true" />              
</context>